# Entity Framework, Generic Repositories, and Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, repository, moq

I solved my problem, but am not sure why things are working and am asking because I always want to know why things work the way they do.

Ok, I am developing an MVC 3 application am utilizing a generic repository, unity for DI, and moq for unit testing.  In my unit test for editing an item, my controller initially had this as follows:
AnEntity obj = _anEntityService.GetById(id);

however, when my unit test was calling the Edit(1) in the controller, null was being returned.  When I changed the read to be
AnEntity obj = _anEntityService.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

it returned the mocked item correctly.

Now, I am glad I figured it out, however, I am still scratching my head as to why that worked for unit testing, but the GetById was working as I was running the application.

Any insight would be most helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the mocked data:

```
public class AdministrationMockData
{
    #region Administration Mock Data
    #region County Mock Data
    public static void CreateCounty(ref Mock<ICountyService> mock)
    {
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetAll()).Returns(new List<County> 
        {
    new County { Id = 1, Name = "Adams", StateId = 39, IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" },
    new County { Id = 2, Name = "Berks",  StateId = 39, IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" },
    new County { Id = 3, Name = "Chester",  StateId = 39, IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" },
    new County { Id = 4, Name = "York",  StateId = 39, IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" },
    new County { Id = 5, Name = "Baltimore",  StateId = 21, IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" },
    new County { Id = 6, Name = "Montgomery",  StateId = 21, IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" }
  }.AsQueryable());
    }
    #endregion County Mock Data

    #region State Mock Data
    public static void CreateState(ref Mock<IStateService> mock)
    {
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetAll()).Returns(new List<State> 
        {
    new State { Id = 21, Name = "Maryland", Code = "MD", IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" },
    new State { Id = 39, Name = "Pennsylvania",  Code = "PA", IsActive = true, LastChangedDate = DateTime.Now, LastChangedBy = "dba", AddedDate = DateTime.Now, AddedBy = "dba" }        
  }.AsQueryable());
    }
    #endregion State Mock Data
    #endregion Administration Mock Data
}
```

Here is the Unit Test for Edit

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Can_Edit_County()
    {
        // Arrange
        // - create the mock repositories
        Mock<ICountyService> mockCounty = new Mock<ICountyService>();
        Mock<IStateService> mockState = new Mock<IStateService>();
        AdministrationMockData.CreateCounty(ref mockCounty);
        AdministrationMockData.CreateState(ref mockState);

        // Arrange
        // - create a controller and make the page size 6 items
        CountyController controller = new CountyController(mockCounty.Object, mockState.Object);
        controller.PageSize = 6;
        controller.Testing = true;

        // Act
        County c1 = controller.Edit(1).ViewData.Model as County;
        County c2 = controller.Edit(2).ViewData.Model as County;
        County c3 = controller.Edit(3).ViewData.Model as County;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, c1.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, c2.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, c3.Id);
    }
```

Here is the controller edit routine:

```
    public ViewResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //County obj = _countyService.GetById(id);
        County obj = _countyService.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (!Testing)
        {
            PopulateCountyDropDownLists(obj.StateId);
        }
        return View(obj);
    }
```

I have a generic repository and interface repository which is instantiated by TEntity for each specific entity and also have a service and interface service to execute the repositories.  My repository and service is based on: http://efmvc.codeplex.com/releases/view/58663

Comment: I wouldn't call it solving the problem. You are downloading all the items and perform the filtering on the client-side which will influence your application performance. Anyway could you please share the code that you used in your test to configure the mock?

Comment: How is the data being mocked up? Are you setting the ID correctly? Like dmusial said, code would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You get null because you never setup your `CountyService` to return proper data when calling `GetById`. Add the below code for setting up the mock and you'll be good to go with the `GetById` method:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetById(1).Returns(new State { Id = 1, ... });
```

or set it up to work with any argument passed to the mothod:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetById(It.IsAny<int>()).Returns(new State { ... });
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it.  Just getting into the unit testing thing as it is important.